# How to retreive current test case name in nightwach

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, nightwatch.js

I m working with balloon pop up which will invoke for currently running test case, I need to pass the current test case name to that balloon popup.I tried with `browser.currentTest` but it is returning [object, object]. Is there any other way of retrieving the current test case name,if so can someone help me in retrieving the current test case name. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is inside currentTest ? json or anything else?

Comment: Use process.env.__NIGHTWATCH_ENV_KEY

Comment: I dont know actually what is there inside of currentTest as it is a library method. but my test contains javscript code only

Comment: **@Quality Products**, tried with process.env.__NIGHTWATCH_ENV_KEY but it is returning 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
browser.currentTest.module
```

In nightwatch, you have access to the name of the currentTest using .module. It's not in the docs, it just came up by logging

```
var keys = Object.keys(client.currentTest)
```

to the console like:

```
console.log(keys)
```

from the base test class. Adding that to the prototype isn't even necessary as it's available in any test. "module" is a property of the Test object in Nightwatch.

Also note that, from experience, the seemingly inaptly named browser.currentTest.name is *not* what you want. It's an array of numbers whose purpose I have yet to deduce...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11802104)

Comment: I'm not critiquing, or requesting clarification. In nightwatch, you have access to the name of the currentTest using .module. It's not in the docs, it just came up by logging var keys = Object.keys(client.currentTest) to the console  like: console.log(keys) from the base test class. Adding that to the prototype isn't even necessary as it's available in any test. "module" is the property of Test Object in Nightwatch. Are you sure that this doesn't answer 
the question for @ramgulla?

Comment: Sorry, @Quali, my comment was a boilerplate default option from the review queue. What I should've said is that additional information would have been useful - your comment in reply to me is a perfect example. Could you edit your answer to include that additional info? Or I can do so. Thanks!

Comment: browser.currentTest (or client.currentTest) returns undefined